# Sublime3's Markdown highlighting is not working in Ubuntu (it works well in Windows)

Tags: sublimetext3, markdown, ubuntu-16.04

Sublime 3 with monokai theme works just fine in Windows for markdown, but I use Ubuntu (16.04, 64 bits) much more than my Win10 partition, tags like:

## Hello

Won't get highlight, does anybody know how to fix this? It works well for any other language I select with the language's respective tags, am I missing any plug-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to reinstall Sublime, something went corrupted.